# Sonar with ldap plugin does not use LDAP without domain prefix

Tags: ldap, sonarqube

I'm using sonar 5.6 LTS with LDAP plugin 2.1.0.

The basic LDAP configuation is working fine. Sonar can connect to LDAP (in my case active directory). sonar.log:

```
Test LDAP connection on ldaps://ldap.mycompany:636: OK
```

My user mapping is

```
ldap.user.baseDn=OU=Users,OU=Accounts,DC=mycompany
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))
```

When I try to login with **mycompany\tobi** sonar logs:

```
DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.LdapUsersProvider] Requesting details for user mycompany\tobi
...
DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.LdapUsersProvider] User mycompany\tobi not found in <default>
```

This makes sense as **sAMAccountName** contains the value **tobi** and not **mycompany\tobi**. But when using just **tobi** as login, sonarqube does not connect to LDAP for authentication. I just get "Authentication failed" and the log file contains only

```
DEBUG web[http] POST /sonar/sessions/login | time=235ms
```

Any ideas why sonarqube does not always use LDAP? Thanks, Tobi

Comment: Why you don't use "tobi" instead of "mycompany\tobi" to login ?

Comment: Because sonarqube will not use ldap without the domain prefix. It would just check the local accounts. At least this is what I see in the log files.

Comment: If local account exist, then it will use local, otherwise it will go to LDAP.

Comment: @Godin: Ok, so I guess this is the real issue: when just using `tobi` as login, sonarqube does not search for a LDAP user. I just get "Authentication failed" at the login screen and sonar just logs: `DEBUG web[http] POST /sonar/sessions/login | time=235ms` -> no communication with LDAP (even after deleting all local accounts but admin)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Godin, I've finally found the answer:

The root cause is that I had a local account with the same login credentials before using LDAP. When removing users using the web interface, they are not removed permanently from the database. Instead, they are just deactivated.

I connected to the (postgresql) database and in the `users` table there were still all old local accounts. So I just changed the `login` column of all deprecated local accounts with

```
UPDATE users SET login='username_local' WHERE login='username'
```

As those accounts are deactivated, they cannot be used to login into sonarqube but should not be removed as some other tables might still have references to them.

Comment: Note that normally you should not touch database to prevent corruption of data and inconsistent state of database. I can't find ticket, but problem that you describe supposed to be fixed in latest versions (> 5.6) and doesn't require manual changes in database.

Comment: You are right. I've searched all tables for references to the login column to prevent data corruption. But it's a workarkund nevertheless. I've found sonarqubes Jira but it seems there is no way to create a ticket without an account.

Comment: You don't need to create ticket - as I said: this is supposed to be fixed in latest versions of SQ (> 5.6).